# Fitting different data sets with different models and 2 free variables using FindFit

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I have a T1 equation from which I got two noisy datasets, one for y=0 (datax) and the other for x=0 (datay) (t is always equal to 1):

```
Dif = 0.00000013; K0 = 0.5; z = 0; linf\[Alpha] = 0.0;

T1[x_, y_, t_, b_, l_, d_, m_, Intens_] /; 
  NumberQ[x] && NumberQ[y] && NumberQ[b] && NumberQ[l] && NumberQ[d] &&
    NumberQ[m] && NumberQ[Intens] := 
 Intens/(2*\[Pi]*K0)*
  NIntegrate[
   Sqrt[1 + m^2]*
    Erfc[Sqrt[(x - \[Alpha])^2 + (y - \[Beta])^2 + (z - (m*\[Alpha] - 
            d))^2]/Sqrt[
       Dif*4*t]]/(Sqrt[(x - \[Alpha])^2 + (y - \[Beta])^2 + (z - (m*\
\[Alpha] - d))^2]), {\[Beta], -b/2, b/2}, {\[Alpha], linf\[Alpha], 
    l*(1/(1 + m^2))}]
```

```
Block[{y = 0, t = 1, b = 0.001, l = 0.001, d = 0.0001, 
   m = -Tan[45*Pi/180], Intens = 25000}, 
  datax = Table[{x, 
     T1[x, y, t, b, l, d, m, Intens] + 
      Random[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]]}, {x, -0.002, 0.002, 
     0.000015}]];
```

```
Block[{x = 0, t = 1, b = 0.001, l = 0.001, d = 0.0001, 
   m = -Tan[45*Pi/180], Intens = 25000}, 
  datay = Table[{y, 
     T1[x, y, t, b, l, d, m, Intens] + 
      Random[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]]}, {y, -0.002, 0.002, 
     0.000015}]];
```

My goal is to find the best fit parameters for both datasets. The parameters are {b,l,d,m,Intens}, and must be the same for the fit of datax and datay. The free variables instead are {x,y}. (t=1)

The main problem is that FindFit has to look for the same optimal values of the parameters {b,l,d,m,Intens} passing from T1 with y=0 for datax, to T1 with x=0 for datay. It would also be useful not to impose initial search values for the parameters, as I should not know them. Always if this is possible

The fit, for example, only for datax is of this type and it works:

```
fitx = FindFit[datax, 
  T1[x, 0, 1, b, l, d, m, 
   Intens], {{b, 0.0015}, {l, 0.0015}, {d, 0.00015}, {m, -1}, {Intens,
     20000}}, x, Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"]
{b -> 0.00120948, l -> 0.000999963, d -> 0.000084307, m -> -1.00055, 
 Intens -> 22038.8}
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to solve my problem?

Comment: Take a look at this repository function. I think it may help you with what you need:
https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultiNonlinearModelFit

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm taking a look but I understand that for 2 free variables the system does not work. Or maybe I didn't understand something

Comment: I think it should work. You should format your datasets as matrices `{{x, y, T1}..}` (where either the x or y column is 0) and then specify the fit function as `T1[x, y, 1, b, l, d, m, Intens]`. Then you can specify that `x` and `y` are independent variables and the rest as fit parameters.

Comment: You have to excuse me but I'm a newbie. I just can't use this repository function. How do you proceed to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can learn from that example. (I just wanted to avoid waiting for the long caclulations in your post.)

```
model = a Exp[-b ((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2)];

pl = Plot3D[1.2 Exp[-34 ((x - .02)^2 + (y - .07)^2)], 
          {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]];

data1 = Table[{x, 0, 
1.2 Exp[-34 ((x - .02)^2 + (0 - .07)^2)] + 
 RandomReal[{-.1, .1}]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];

data2 = Table[{0, y, 
1.2 Exp[-34 ((0 - .02)^2 + (y - .07)^2)] + 
 RandomReal[{-.1, .1}]}, {y, 0, 1, .01}];

data12 = Join[data1, data2];

lp = ListPointPlot3D[data12, PlotStyle -> Red];

Show[pl, lp]
```

[image]

```
fit = FindFit[data12, 
   model, {{a, 1}, {b, 30}, {x0, .1}, {y0, .1}}, {x, y}]

(*   {a -> 1.2083, b -> 35.4499, 
      x0 -> 0.0248425, y0 -> 0.0709918}   *)
```

Comment: It solved my problem! Mistake in data creation. Thanks a lot